# iOS: Eureka forms. How to change tint on Picker from PickerInputRow

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

## Scope

- iOS: 10.0
- Eureka: 3.0

How to configure properties of the presented view on eg: `MultipleSelectorRow<T>`?

## Code

From the Example project, here's one `MultipleSelectorRow`

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<Emoji>() {
                        $0.title = "MultipleSelectorRow"
                        $0.options = [, , , , , ]
                        $0.value = [, , ]
                    }.onPresent { from, to in
                        to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(RowsExampleViewController.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
                    }.cellSetup { cell, row in
                cell.tintColor = .orange
        }
```

This code produces a selector view where the tint is default, rather than whatever the tint can be setup for the Row's cell itself (in this case, `.orange`):

[image: MultipleSelectorRow present tint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to configure the presented VC in the `onPresent` callback. There are more things that can be configured, just need to dive in to the classes.

### Configuration

Simply define `selectableRowCellSetup` in a similar way to `[cellSetup][1]`

```
...
.onPresent { from, to in
  to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(RowsExampleViewController.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
  to.selectableRowCellSetup = { cell, row in
    cell.tintColor = .red
  }
}
...
```

### Result

[image]